# how to reuse the variable in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, global-variables, procfs

```
extern unsigned long current_rx_time;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(current_rx_time);
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{

current_rx_time = jiffies;

}
```

I modified the kernel source code in dev.c as shown above. Later I am creating a loadable kernel module in procfs and using the currentrx_time to send it to user space as shown below :

```
static int my_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    //I AM JUST PRINTING THAT VALUE BELOW

    seq_printf(m, "%lu\n", current_rx_time *1000/HZ);

    return 0;
}
```

but I am getting a error when I compile my module above as `current_rx_time` is undeclared. Could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to declare your variable and then you can EXPORT it.

so just declare it as in dev.c

```
unsigned long current_rx_time;
```

then export it as in dev.c

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(current_rx_time);
```

and in other loadable module where you want to use it (let's say in temp2.c)...

```
extern unsigned long current_rx_time;
```

Now make sure when you going to compile temp2.c at that time dev.c is also getting compile.

Answer (score 0):

The second code needs to declare the external variable, so the linker can know that it's coming from the outside:

```
extern unsigned long current_rx_time;
```